# <portlet:actionURL> unable to go action page in liferay

Tags: liferay-6

I am developing a liferay portlet I just called an action function from view.jsp page.
I already implemented this code in my previous portlets but now I don't know why it is not working 
code of the portlet is
in view.jsp

```
 <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/portlet_2_0" prefix="portlet" %>
 <portlet:defineObjects />

 <portlet:actionURL var="insert" name="interlope"></portlet:actionURL>

 <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">    
  function embedFun()
  { 
 try
 {
 alert(insert.toString());
      document.getElementById('insertpart').action='<%=insert.toString()%>';                                 
 document.getElementById('insertpart').submit();
 }
 catch(err)
 {
     alert("embedfun of shop_search view.jsp: "+err);
 }
     } 
      </script> 


and my action class is 

package com.shop.search;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.sql.Date;
import java.util.List;

import javax.portlet.ActionRequest;
import javax.portlet.ActionResponse;
import javax.portlet.PortletException;
import javax.portlet.ProcessAction;
import javax.portlet.RenderRequest;
import javax.portlet.RenderResponse;
import javax.portlet.ResourceRequest;
import javax.portlet.ResourceResponse;

import shop.search.item.model.Cart;
import shop.search.item.model.Item;
import shop.search.item.model.available;
import shop.search.item.model.impl.CartImpl;
import shop.search.item.service.CartLocalServiceUtil;
import shop.search.item.service.ItemLocalServiceUtil;
import shop.search.item.service.availableLocalServiceUtil;

import com.liferay.compat.portal.util.PortalUtil;
import com.liferay.counter.service.CounterLocalServiceUtil;
import com.liferay.portal.PortalException;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.exception.SystemException;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.ParamUtil;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.WebKeys;
import com.liferay.portal.model.PortletPreferences;
import com.liferay.portal.model.User;
import com.liferay.portal.theme.ThemeDisplay;
import com.liferay.util.bridges.mvc.MVCPortlet;

/**
 * Portlet implementation class Shop_SearchPortlet
 */
public class Shop_SearchPortlet extends MVCPortlet 
{

    @ProcessAction(name="interlope")
    public void interlope(ActionRequest req, ActionResponse res)
            throws PortletException, SystemException,  RemoteException
            {
                String searchVal=req.getParameter("inputText");
                List<Item> tbl=null;
                if(searchVal!=null)
                {
                    tbl=ItemLocalServiceUtil.findItemByBrand(searchVal);
                    if(tbl!=null)
                    {
                        req.setAttribute("tblval",tbl);
                        System.out.println("@@@@@@@@@@@@ val of obj:  "+tbl);


    enter code here
                    }
                    else
                        System.out.println("@@@@@@@@   val of tbl obj: "+tbl);      
                }   
            }}
`                                                                                   //redirect to insert action class
 { 
     try
     {
     alert(insert.toString());
     document.getElementById('insertpart').action='<%=insert.toString()%>';                              
     document.getElementById('insertpart').submit();
     }
     catch(err)
     {
         alert("embedfun of shop_search view.jsp: "+err);
     }
} 
</script>

<form method="post" id="insertpart">
    <table>
     <tr>       
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="inputText" name="inputText">
                <input type="button" value="search" name="submitbutton" onclick="embedFun();">
            </td>
        </tr>
     <tr>
        </tabale>
```

If you notice in my code I added try and catch block in javascript code to what is the value of insert and I got that there is no value in insert means no url coming in insert in
 no syntax problem 
nothing but out put is not coming please help me.
  I already completed another same as this one that was working fine. Because of some issue I have changed my workspace is this may be the cause, even I ask my friend about this issue he told no relation with change of workspace to create some problem in code.

Answer (score 0):

This problem arise because I have use some component as submit may be name of button or input type="submit" that's create that problem. We have to always try to gives some unique name to our component and always never use the predefined method name etc. 
This solve my problem 
thanks and regards 
asif aftab